# What do you call a person who works on old home movies and paper photographs?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests, cinema, photography

What do you call a person who works on old home movies and paper photographs? I'm not talking about someone who operates a camera.  Simply just scans, edits, and creates from photographs and old video (like VHS or Super 8).

Comment: A Luddite, I suppose.

Comment: Professionally, such a person would be called an *archivist*, so *amateur archivist*, perhaps?

Comment: You can work all you want to on old home movies and photographs, that does not make you an archivist. That would mean cataloging or categorizing them in some sort of order. Also, I fail to see how working on home movies (editing them??) and photos are the same thing. Also, what do you mean by ***working on***?? How can you scan, edit and create from old video? I guess you can PRINT IMAGES of old video.

Comment: A photography collage maker?

Answer (score 1):

This person performs **media conversion** if they take old photos/videos and converts them to modern formats.

If they are making art or decorative objects (collages, scrapbooks, decoupage, etc.) then I don't think there's a particular name for that sub-genre.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mick, how about *archivist*?

From M-W:

> [*archivist*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archivist): a
>   person in charge of archives
>
> [archive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archive): a
>   repository or collection especially of information

Example:

> My sister Jean is our family *archivist*. She maintains all of our old
>   home movies and paper photographs. She edits, scans, creates, and shares videos
>   and albums in modern electronic formats.